# Getting Stripe secret error after cloning Google's github repository

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm trying to follow this source code on github:

(https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe)

for creating stripe payment using Firebase, I cloned the repository but I still getting this error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'secret' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/radef/Documents/Firebase/functions/index.js:25:59)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
```

Comment: Did you follow the [Deploy and Test](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe#deploy-and-test) section on the readme?

Comment: Seconding Vitor's question. You're likely seeing this error because you forgot to add the secret key to your config: `firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret=<YOUR STRIPE SECRET KEY>`

Comment: How to add to config